# Whats the value of $\int^{\pi/2}_{0}u(x)\cos2xdx$ if $u(x)=\int^x_0 \frac{t}{\sin t}dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Whats the value of $\int^{\pi/2}_{0}u(x)\cos2xdx$ if $u(x)=\int^x_0 \frac{t}{\sin t}dt$?

I'm thinking $\int^{\pi/2}_{0}(U(x)-U(0))\cos2xdx$ where $U$ is the antiderivative of $t/\sin t$ but I don't think that is the solution since this is from a calc 2 class.

Comment: $$\text{Hint:}\qquad\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^x\Box\,dt\,dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_t^{\pi/2}\Box\,dx\,dt.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a cute integration-by-parts and Fundamental Theorem problem.  Let $u=u(x)$ and $dv = \cos 2x$ and you get

$$\left. u(x)\frac{\sin 2x}{2}\right|_0^{\pi/2} - \int_0^{\pi/2} 
\frac{x}{\sin x} \frac{\sin 2x}{2} \; dx.$$

It doesn't matter the values of $u(x)$ that those two points because the $\sin$ factor is zero.  The new integral is easy after you do the double angle identity.